# Opening a aspx page in new tab on clicking Hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, hyperlink

```
   Response.Write("<td><a href= view5.aspx?file=" + strheadlinesid + "\\" + FI.Name + "> " +
            FI.Name + "</a></td>");
```

I have above line in my code which is redirecting my page to view5.aspx.                    But I want to open the view5.aspx in new tab how can I do that.

Comment: add target="_blank" after the href prop.

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.Write("<td><a target='blank' href= view5.aspx?file=" + strheadlinesid + "\\" + FI.Name + "> " +
            FI.Name + "</a></td>");
```

Add target='blank' in a tag